# Gecko version number format in User-Agent strings for Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, android, http, headers, user-agent

Here are four User-Agent (HTTP header) strings for Mozilla's Firefox browser.

```
# Linux
Linux / Firefox 42: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
# Mac
Mac / Firefox 42: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
# Windows
Windows / Firefox 42: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
# Android
Android / Firefox 42: Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:42.0) Gecko/42.0 Firefox/42.0
```

Why is the format of the Gecko version number for Android (**42.0**) completely different from that of the other operating systems (**20100101**)?

What function does it serve to have it in this different format?

Comment: Only the developers will know. You can look at the [source code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code). There may some comments explaining why.

Comment: Thanks.  I know several of their developers contribute here, so hopefully they (or someone else) will provide an answer.